# Drupal Module Not Loading

Tags: web-services, drupal, rest, drupal-6, drupal-modules

We are currently using REST Server Module (plugable module for Services module). This module is dependent on 2 other modules: Autoload and Input Stream.  We upload / installed these modules and they are not able to be activated via the D6 admin panel (checkbox disabled).  Are there common issues with module activation or similar that we may be overlooking or is this a specific problem with the modules?

We are using Drupal 6.19 / PHP 5.2.11

We have also tried installing different versions of these modules and they are not working.

Please note we do not have Drupal development background but need to make web services work to power a mobile application.

Any and all recommednations are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

JN

Answer (score 0):

You probably already checked this but did you verify that all the dependencies of the other two modules: Autoload and Input Stream installed and enabled?